# How can I send android beam message to nfc-explorer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nfc, nfc-p2p

How can I send ndef message to nfc-explorer? I try to use source code from nfc explorer but all the time get empty ndef message.

Comment: According to https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11480.pdf, the basic example (section 5.1) should work for peer-to-peer mode with SNEP. Hence that example should work with Android Beam.

Answer (score 0):

You have a full demo implementation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/AndroidBeamDemo/), and read the [official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-beam)

To answer your question, to send a message:

```
public NdefMessage CreateNdefMessage (NfcEvent evt)
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    var text = ("Beam me up!\n\n" + "Beam Time: " +
        time.ToString ("HH:mm:ss"));
    NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage (
        new NdefRecord[]{ CreateMimeRecord (
            "application/com.example.android.beam",
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (text)) });
        } };
    return msg;
}

public NdefRecord CreateMimeRecord (String mimeType, byte [] payload)
{
    byte [] mimeBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (mimeType);
    NdefRecord mimeRecord = new NdefRecord (
        NdefRecord.TnfMimeMedia, mimeBytes, new byte [0], payload);
    return mimeRecord;
}
```